# Text between two forms with color in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms with a main window and a second window. The main window (`Form1`) shall get text from the second window (`Form2`)

My second window (`Form2`) can write text from form 2 to form 1. In the class I can choose color for my text but my problem is that when I push the button who shall send the text it just comes the text without the color I choose so its just black text in `Form1` when I send example yellow.

I'm not a C# expert since I'm pretty new at this. I'm sure its a pretty simple problem to fix but for me its not so easy.

`Form1.cs`:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace tester
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
     public string text;
     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 NewForm2 = new Form2(this);
        NewForm2.Show();
    }

    internal void populate()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

`Form2.cs`:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace Tester
   {
   public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
    Form1 texting;
    public Form2(Form1 iForm)
    {
        texting = iForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        texting.text = richTextBox1.Text;
        texting.populate();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( MyColorDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            richTextBox1.ForeColor = MyColorDialog.Color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A string variable only contains "the string" (Who would have thought?). 
What you want is to also take over the "design" of the Texbox. So easiest way is to make the Textbox public, instead of the string variable. Then say something linke Form1.YourBox.ForeColor = richTextBox1.ForeColor....

Answer (score 0):

Just as you are making `public string text` in your Form1, you could make a `public Color rictTextBoxColor` property. Then setting it as well, and referring to it in your populate method